# Ordem de plotagem scatterplot ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Eu estou fazendo um scatterplot e mapeando os pontos por cor (duas categorias) e tamanho (uma variável discreta).

Os pontos devem se sobrepor, pois são medidas de um mesmo lugar, em épocas diferentes

O problema é: o ponto de maior tamanho é plotado 'na frente' do menor, aí sobrepõe.
Mesmo usando alpha pra deixar 'transparente' tá ficando muito feio.

Existe algum jeito de eu inverter a ordem que o ggplot plota as variáveis?

Aqui tá um print do gráfico. Idealmente, os pontos pretos deveriam ser plotados atrás dos pontos vermelhos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Edit:

```
LIGHT <-
 structure(list(Sensor = c("Sensor 01", "Sensor 02", 
 "Sensor 03", "Sensor 04", "Sensor 05", "Sensor 06", 
 "Sensor 07", "Sensor 08", "Sensor 09", "Sensor 10", 
 "Sensor 11", "Sensor 12", "Sensor 13", "Sensor 14", 
 "Sensor 15", "Sensor 01", "Sensor 02", "Sensor 03", 
 "Sensor 04", "Sensor 05"), Light = c(29.2326025, 
 19.1888217741935, 20.2879273387097, 22.6006463709677, 
 29.4652291129032, 31.4922126612903, 18.0189039516129, 
 44.2132503225806, 19.6836093548387, 29.6778536290323, 
 23.7034666935484, 37.4008766935484, 32.4513981451613, 
 57.5753566129032, 41.8583696774194, 64.6308373214286, 
 44.2330882142857, 45.8567069642857, 61.8264760714286, 
 57.66113125), Dif_PAR.sensor = c(136.820568709677, 
 146.864349435484, 145.765243870968, 143.45252483871, 
 136.587942096774, 134.560958548387, 148.034267258065, 
 121.839920887097, 146.369561854839, 136.375317580645, 
 142.349704516129, 128.652294516129, 133.601773064516, 
 108.477814596774, 124.194801532258, 81.3658292857143, 
 101.763578392857, 100.139959642857, 84.1701905357143, 
 88.3355353571429), Percent_of_PAR = c(19.0689480982097, 
 14.2716407995484, 15.1293532713629, 15.8380714606935, 
 17.456968456871, 18.0777406968065, 13.7234488349113, 
 72.7551326408065, 11.6857118804435, 21.3044665453226, 
 16.434219278871, 25.781927983129, 23.9310200270565, 
 42.2960034949194, 32.4126078909758, 39.0122370998214, 
 26.402147205, 30.3298732019643, 36.2347200010714, 
 31.7127142146429), Height = c(11.3, 11.65, 12.8, 13.1, 
 13.1, 13.45, 13.5, 15.05, 16.15, 16.5, 17.7, 18.45, 18.5, 
 19, 20.1, 11.3, 11.65, 12.8, 13.1, 13.1), North = c(0, 0, 
 0, 1.5, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1.9, 2.3, 0.4, 0, 4.2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
 1.5, 3), South = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 1.5, 0.7, 0, 0, 0, 
 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), East = c(0.3, 0, 1.9, 0, 0.7, 
 0, 0, 0.3, 0, 0.6, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0.3, 0, 1.9, 0, 0.7), 
 West = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.5, 0.1, 0, 1.9, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ), Northeast = c(0, 0, 2.45, 1.95, 3.55, 
 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.9, 1.6, 0, 0, 0, 1.5, 0, 0, 2.45, 1.95, 3.55), 
 Northwest = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3.25, 0, 0, 0, 4.6, 
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Southeast = c(0.85, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
 1.3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.85, 0, 0, 0, 0), Southwest = c(0, 
 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.95, 1.95, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.5, 0, 0.8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
 0, 0), Dist_to_tree_center = c(0.85, 0, 2.45, 1.95, 3.55, 
 2.95, 1.95, 1.3, 3.25, 2.9, 1.6, 2.5, 4.6, 0.8, 1.5, 0.85, 
 0, 2.45, 1.95, 3.55), N_S = c(-0.5, 0, 0.5, 1.9, 3.4, -0.5, 
 -1.9, -1.1, 2.3, 2.7, 0.8, -0.5, 4.6, -0.6, 1.4, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 
 1.9, 3.4), E_W = c(0.7, 0, 2.4, 0.5, 1.1, -2.9, -0.5, 0.7, 
 -2.3, 1, 1.4, -2.4, -0.5, -0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0, 2.4, 0.5, 1.1), 
 Aspect = c("Southeast", "On the bole", "Northeast", 
 "Northeast", "Northeast", "Southwest", "Southwest", 
 "Southeast", "Northwest", "Northeast", "Northeast", 
 "Southwest", "Northwest", "Southwest", "Northeast", 
 "Southeast", "On the bole", "Northeast", "Northeast", 
 "Northeast"), Leaf_set = c("With", "With", "With", 
 "With", "With", "With", "With", "With", "With", "With", 
 "With", "With", "With", "With", "With", "Without", 
 "Without", "Without", "Without", "Without")), 
 row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

O código que eu usei foi esse:

```
ggplight <- ggplot(LIGHT, aes(x=Dist_to_tree_center, y=Height, size = Percent_of_PAR, color=Leaf_set))+
  scale_color_manual(values=colors, labels=c("With leaves", "Without leaves"))+
  geom_point(alpha=.4) + 
  scale_size(range = c(3, 15), name="Light")+
  
  labs(x = 'Distance to tree centre (m)', y = 'Height (m)', color='', title = '(b)', subtitle = '')+
  
  theme_classic(base_size = 30)+
  theme(panel.background = element_blank())+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank())+
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank())+
  theme(plot.background = element_blank())+
  guides(color = FALSE)+
  theme(legend.position=c(1,0.1), legend.justification=c(1,-0.1))+
  theme(legend.background = element_rect(fill="transparent"))
```

Comment: Pode, por favor, **editar a pergunta** com a saída de `dput(LIGHT)` ou, se a base for muito grande, de `dput(head(LIGHT, 20))`?

Comment: Vê se era isso, por favor.

Comment: Sim era isso mesmo, obrigado.

Comment: No entanto, com os dados da pergunta, não há pontos de cores diferentes sobrepostos.

Comment: Desculpa se tá confuso. O que eu fiz foi: usei "Height" no eixo y e "Dist_to_tree_center" no eixo x. os valores plotados mapeados com size são os de "Percent_of_PAR" e usei cor pra mapear "Leaf_set".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma maneira de plotar os pontos mais pequenos por cima dos maiores é reparar que os pontos mais pequenos correspondem ao `Leaf_set == "With"` e usar duas `geom_point`, filtrando o `Leaf_set` correspondente a cada um dos valores. Primeiro a `"Without"` e de seguida a `"With"`.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplight <- ggplot(LIGHT, aes(Dist_to_tree_center, Height, size = Percent_of_PAR, color = Leaf_set))+
  geom_point(
    data = subset(LIGHT, Leaf_set == "Without"),
    alpha = 0.6
  ) +
  geom_point(
    data = subset(LIGHT, Leaf_set == "With"),
    alpha = 0.6
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(breaks = c("With", "Without"), values = colors) +
  scale_size(range = c(3, 15), name="Light")+
  labs(x = 'Distance to tree centre (m)', y = 'Height (m)', color='', title = '(b)', subtitle = '') +
  guides(color = "none") +
  theme_Mariana()

ggplight
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

### `theme` do gráfico

```
theme_Mariana <- function(){ 
    theme_classic() + 
    theme(
        title = element_text(face = "bold"),
        axis.title = element_text(face = "bold"),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        plot.background = element_blank(),
        legend.title = element_text(face = "bold"),
        legend.text = element_text(face = "bold"),
        legend.position = c(1, 0.05), 
        legend.justification = c("right", "bottom"),
        legend.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent")
    )
}
```

Comment: Vou rodar aqui meu script e confirmar os dados, só um instante, por favor.

Comment: Ah, acho que entendi o que houve. Quando eu enviei o output de "dput(head(LIGHT, 20))" não pegou todo o conjunto de dados, então ficaram faltando os dados referentes a algumas sobreposições. Mas algumas saíram (os 5 pontos da parte inferior). É exatamente isso que acontece no meu gráfico. Queria um jeito de plotar o círculo maior por baixo, invertendo a ordem com que eles se sobrepõem.

Comment: @Mariana O códiog anterior estava errado, troquei as cores e não consegui ver nada de errado. Veja agora.

Comment: É isso sim! O que você trocou? \o/

Comment: AAAhh, achei agora o que você escreveu!! Desculpa, primeira vez usando aqui. Obrigada, Rui!! Um ótimo domingo!

Comment: @Mariana O que fazer quando [alguém responde](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) às suas perguntas.

Comment: Ahhh, entendi! Acho que eu fiz certo, mas se estiver errado, me diz que eu mudo.
Pôxa, de novo, muito obrigada!